# Android error on reading text file on remote server

Tags: android, file, url, urlconnection

I try to read a text file on a server.  But i don't have the test returned.  Seems I have a Exception error.

How to see the error in eclipse, or displaying the error ?

If I try to log the erreor, the app go closed. (Log.e("Exception --->",e.getMessage());)

The code here after doent work.

```
public static String getText(String urlAdress) {
    String text_file = "";
    BufferedReader in = null;
    try {
        // create a url object
        URL url = new URL(urlAdress);

        // create a urlconnection object
        URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();

        // Read all the text returned by the server
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                urlConnection.getInputStream()));
        String str;
        while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
            // str is one line of text; readLine() strips the newline
            // character(s)
            text_file = text_file + str;
        }
        in.close();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        text_file = "error";
        Log.e("MalformedURLException --->", e.getMessage());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        text_file = "error";
        Log.e("IOException --->", e.getMessage());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        text_file = "error";
        // Log.e("Exception --->",e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (in != null) {
            try {
                in.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("finally IOException --->",
                        "Exception trying to close BufferedReader");
            }
        }

    }

    return text_file;
}
```

Any Idea ?

Thanks,

Comment: Here is what I have in LogCat :

04-15 22:16:31.016: W/System.err(26558): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
04-15 22:16:31.036: W/System.err(26558):  at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1178)
04-15 22:16:31.036: W/System.err(26558):  at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:394)
04-15 22:16:31.036: W/System.err(26558):  at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:245)
04-15 22:16:31.036: W/System.err(26558):  at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:220)

...

Comment: Please use a StringBuffer to create the String. Don't do text_file = text_file + str; as it is bad practise, and it is inefficient!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, take a look at [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html). This means you need to move all that code from main thread to another thread.

Comment: Thanks,

I read carefully the logcat, and it was written on the first line (as I copied above).

Only to check, I disabeld the Strictmode Policy.

I have to rewrite this process on other part of the script.

André.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the charset

```
 connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", charset);
```

and get rid of the **BufferedReader**. Http does not ensure to send newlines.

Maybe use Apache Streams

http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/apidocs/org/apache/commons/fileupload/util/Streams.html

```
text_file = Streams.asString (urlConnection.getInputStream());
```